# How to nest the transaction data in JSON form with SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am referring to [Format Nested JSON Output with PATH Mode - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-nested-json-output-with-path-mode-sql-server)

I have two table User and Notification with following fields:

> **User:** Id, Name
>
> **Notification:** Id, UserId , Message

How to get result in the following format :

```
[
   {
      Id: 1
      Name: User
      Notifications : [
      {
          Id:2,
          Message:'XYZ'
      }, 
      {
          Id:3,
          Message:'ABC'
      }]
   },

   {
      Id: 2
      Name: User
      Notifications : [
      {
          Id:3,
          Message:'XYZ'
      }, 
      {
          Id:4,
          Message:'ABC'
      }]
   }
]
```

How to nest the transaction data in JSON form with SQL server?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Tried the following and got the solution. This is first time I am using JSON in sql server 2016.

```
SELECT [U].[Id], [U].[Name],[T].[Id] , [T].[Message] FROM [User] [U]
OUTER APPLY (SELECT  [T].[Id] , [T].[Message] FROM [Transaction] [T] WHERE [T].[UserId] = [U].[Id]) Transaction
FOR JSON AUTO
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{"Id":64629,
   "Name":"XYZ",
  "Transaction":
  [
    { "Id":10 , "Message": "xyz"},
    { "Id":11 , "Message": "xyz1"},
    { "Id":12 , "Message": "xyz2"},
   ]
  }
]
```